# Discord bot slash command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm trying to create a bot with multiple commands on discord, I was able to implement it for one command as per sample:

```
{
    "name": "blep",
    "description": "Send a random adorable animal photo",
    "options": [
        {
            "name": "animal",
            "description": "The type of animal",
            "type": 3,
            "required": True,
            "choices": [
                {
                    "name": "Dog",
                    "value": "animal_dog"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Cat",
                    "value": "animal_cat"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Penguin",
                    "value": "animal_penguin"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "only_smol",
            "description": "Whether to show only baby animals",
            "type": 5,
            "required": False
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to add another command, I try to modify the JSON to be an array but it does not accept it, I also try to create multiple objects on the JSON also does not work, does anyone know-how is the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `<ApplicationCommandManager>.create(<ApplicationCommandData>)` method again, where the new `<ApplicationCommandData>` is your new commands data object.

Comment: So need to make one call for each command? That is what I was thinking too. Very ugly for people using lambda functions :(

Comment: Yes. You could however create a single command that would serve as kind of a prefix and then easily create multiple sub commands on that command using its options property.

Comment: the problem is I get too many requests response sending all the commands on different requests

Comment: Sorry I couldn't quite understand that @Icaro, could you rephrase?